# What is the proper way to use struct in C?

Tags: c

I know struct in C is a collection of data, but I'm not sure if I can manipulate it in the following way:-

Say hypothetically I have something like the following:

```
typedef struct { 
    char id[IDSIZE];
    name name;
    int score;
} record;
```

If I wanted to record data, can I simply have a line like:

```
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", &record);
```

to store the line to the record itself?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: No, you need to specify each element as a parameter.

Comment: Why not just try it? See what happens. If it fails try to understand the error message (google is your friend). If you didn't get it come back to SO.

Comment: What type is `name`?  Certainly important to provide good alternatives

Comment: name is actually another struct, sorry I just posted a piece of the code.

Answer (score 3):

`record` is your type name. Like `int` or `char`. So you have to declare a variable of type `record`.

```
record currentRecord;
```

---

`sscanf` needs one variable address for every format token

```
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", &currentRecord); //Fail
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d", &currentRecord.id, &currentRecord.name, &currentRecord.score); //This will work only if name is type of char*
```

---

`name name` won't work. Variable and type name must be different.

Comment: *Variable and type name must be different.* - reference for this? `gcc -std=c11` does not complain.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by JD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088250/434551) already points out the problems and how to fix them. I wont to repeat them here to address just that.

My suggestion is to create couple of functions:

```
int sscanf_record(char str[], record *rec)
{
   int n = sscanf(str, "%s %s %d", rec->id, rec->name, &(rec->id));
   if ( n == EOF )
   {
      return n;
   }
   return ( n == 3 ? 1 : 0);
}

int fscanf_record(FILE* fptr, record *rec)
{
   int n = fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %d", rec->id, rec->name, &(rec->id));
   if ( n == EOF )
   {
      return n;
   }
   return ( n == 3 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Then, in rest of our code, you can these functions instead of having to repeat the details.

```
record myrecord;
if ( sscanf_record(line, &myrecord) != 1 )
{
   // Problem. Deal with it.
}
else
{
   // Use the data
}
```